# Connect to Azure SQL with Azure AD and MFA with Dbeaver client 7.0.5 (latest version)

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, dbeaver

Is there a way to AUTHENTICATE to Azure Sql DB with DBeaver with MFA enabled? Our organization use Azure Active Directory Universal - Universal with MFA to authenticate user to the DBs. Is there a way to use Dbeaver instead of MSSMS?

Comment: Have you tried using Azure Data Studio? You might wish to consider using a tool that is more suited to the platform.

Answer (score 3):

The tool uses the jdbc driver to connect azure SQL. Now, the driver does not support Azure AD with MFA. So we have no way to do these. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017) and [here](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/5754)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you may want, but here follows how mine is set for Azure SQL Server:

**1) Proxy Bypass**:

- Window → Preferences → General → Network Connections

Set **Active Provider** as **Manual** and edit both **HTTP** and **HTTPS** with your organization proxy config

[image: Proxy bypass config]

**2) Proxy for Drivers Download**:

- Window → Preferences → Connections → Drivers

[image: Enable drivers download through proxy]

**3) Create new Azure SQL Server Connection**

- Connect by: Host
- Host: Your host
- Database / Schema: Connection string from **DB name until the end**
- Authentication: Custom

[image: Creating Azure SQL Server connection]

**4) On the item 3, click the button "**Driver Settings**" and check following fields:**

- Embedded
- No authentication
- Allow Empty Password

[image: Configuring Azure SQL Server Driver settings]

Check connection and you are ready to go.